# how many channels does windows explorer use for ftp

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, ftp

I did google for that information, but couldn't find any helpful resources.

If it would use multiple channels it would be nice, but I dont know and currently have no network sniffer installed.

Comment: What benefits are you expecting from multi-channel communication with a single FTP server?

Comment: if the load would be evenly balanced over all open channels, then a user that has several channels could probably benefit from more bandwidth for transactions (only in case more than 1 file would be transacted, of course)

Comment: Consider marching an army of five battalions down a road that is only wide enough for five soldiers to march abreast. Does the army arive quicker if you march one soldier from each battalion in five separate lines or march them one battalion at a time? The road doesn't get any wider if you organise your battalions differently.

Comment: no.. it's not only me having an army dude. if I can get 5 soldiers through in the time another user can get only 1 soldier of his army through, who do you think will win the war? :)

Comment: The point is the road only allows 5 soldiers a second, whether that's five soldiers from one battalion or 1 soldier from each of five different battalions.

Comment: It's still not clear? If other accounts are on the same server and they use FTP too, that means it's better if I get more connections to the server than others, because then I could down-/upload more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only one per connection.The FTP specification says that, by default, all data transfers should be over a single connection.

FTP is a TCP based service. It is connection oriented. It needs to establish a connection between two computers through ports. FTP uses two ports. One for data and another for control. When only one port is used there will be only one channel. For more details. 
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol.

Comment: Thanks for that info, didn't know that a spec would prohibit multiple channels. Can anyone prove that?

Comment: FTP is an OLD protocol... no security, no multipath, no multipart... one connection, one pipeline of data.  (it's actually two connections... a control on port 21, data on port 20).  No support for NAT, no.. no.. no..

Comment: K I will elaborate my answer.

Comment: "Can anyone prove that?" - I don't know, have a read of the [1985 FTP specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) and [2007 extensions](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3659)

Comment: actually I thought it could be possible that the ftp functionality would open multiple connections to an ftp server with the same credentials, so that multiple files could be transmitted at the same time.

Comment: @SwissCoder download managers like IDM does exactly that to download via HTTP. But not FTP